# The level set of Sobolev function

Tags: real-analysis, sobolev-spaces, geometric-measure-theory

Let $u\in W^{1,2}(\Omega)$ where $\Omega\subset \mathbb R^2$ is open bounded, smooth boundary. Moreover, we have $0\leq u\leq 1$.

Let set $\Gamma$ be defined as
$$
\Gamma:=\{x\in\Omega,\,\, u(x)=0\}
$$
Then, I am wondering that, what kind of regularity properties of $\Gamma$ can I have? May I have a subset $\Gamma'\subset \Gamma$ such that $\Gamma'$ is $\mathcal H^{1}$ rectifable? or even a $C^1$ curve?

Comment: think of u = 0 for all $x \in \Omega$, nothing you would have.

Comment: @runaround No, because $\Omega$ is assumed nice to start with, so in that case $\Gamma$ is just as nice as $\Omega$.

Comment: @runaround In this case $\Gamma\equiv \Omega$, and I think I just freely choose $\Gamma'$ so that $\Gamma'$ is a $C^\infty$ curve... Or am I missing something very simple?

Comment: @tankonetoone, you could not assume anything when u is constant in $\Omega$. You might need $\nabla u \ne 0$ to invoke implicit function theory to get the smoothess of the boundary. But, I do not recall results on $u\in W^{1,2}(\Omega)$

Comment: @runaround The boundary of $\Omega$ is already smooth...

Comment: @runaround I really got confused now. I am not trying to prove $\Gamma$ itself is good or not (although I am very interested in), but try to show there is a good subset $\Gamma'$ inside $\Gamma$... and in the constant case, the choice of $\Gamma'$ would be easy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For every closed set $\Gamma\subset \Omega$ there is a function $u$ that satisfies the stated requirements, namely 
$$
u(x) = \min(\operatorname{dist}(x,\Gamma), 1)
$$
Consequently, there is nothing you can say about $\Gamma$ other than it's closed with respect to $\Omega$.

Comment: Since the function is not even assumed to be continuous, $\Gamma$ does not need to be closed. However, it is quasi-closed.